# Error While Configure Jest With anglular 6

Tags: jestjs, angular6, ts-jest

I create the angualr Project with following Configuration and Try use jest the install

package.json file is follwing:

```
{
    "name": "angular-assessment",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "3d-force-graph": "^1.56.5",
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
        "@gustafguner/angular-tooltip": "^1.0.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "circular-json": "^0.5.9",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "event-stream": "^4.0.1",
        "gojs": "^2.1.12",
        "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "microsoft-adal-angular6": "^1.3.0",
        "ngx-color": "^4.0.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^7.5.0",
        "ngx-contextmenu": "^5.2.0",
        "ngx-draggable-widget": "^1.0.7",
        "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.3.4",
        "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.2",
        "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
        "ngx-ui-loader": "^7.2.2",
        "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
        "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~6.2.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-spsave": "^3.1.1",
        "husky": "^4.2.5",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "jest": "^27.0.4",
        "jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.4",
        "karma": "~3.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "lint-staged": "^10.2.11",
        "prettier": "2.0.5",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~2.9.2"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
      }
}
```

setupJest.ts File Contain following code:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

geeting this error while npm test

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/reflection'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

I follow this Links:

1]https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library
2]https://www.amadousall.com/how-to-set-up-angular-unit-testing-with-jest/

Answer (score 1):

All of your packages are very old and out of date, this is causing you many problems.  You can hover over each package and update them to the current version of Angular which is 12, you are on AngularJS for angular-build and the rest angular 6.

So what I would do if I was you is install them individually or generate a new angular application.  this is end of life end of support according to Google right now because LTS expired three years ago plus.

before you do that update angular

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
npm install @angular/cli -g
ng n angularjesttest
cd angularjesttest
```

then reinstall each package from npm as the current platform version, this is the problem with older packages.